# Tailwind Merge with Colors on Text and Text Shadows

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

**tl;dr** I have a `text-shadow` utility class in my `tailwind.config.ts` that allows me to change both the dimensions and colors of the shadow. I'm using Tailwind Merge, I can't figure out how to stop `text-shadow-{size/color}` from conflicting with `text-{color}`.

### The Problem

Often in CSS, using text shadows is very helpful for adding cool designs around text or even adding contrast for the text, rather than using a drop shadow. I've been created a `text-shadow` utility class to my Tailwind Config a while ago, and it works great, until I use it on a component that utilizes Tailwind Merge. Tailwind Merge is a great package, but—when using custom utility classes—it can get confused.

### The Solution

Naturally, my goal was to use `extendTailwindMerge` to correct this issue. The documentation on configuring Tailwind Merge is well detailed, but since it only gives `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` for examples, I was a bit confused how to do something specific.

### The Ask

Please look at my `tailwind.config.ts` and custom `twMerge()` function and let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks!

#### The Code

```
// tailwind.config.ts

// * Types
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'
import type { CSSRuleObject, ThemeConfig } from 'tailwindcss/types/config'

/**
 * ### Decimal Alpha to HEX
 * - Converts an RGB decimal alpha value to hexidecimal alpha format
 * @param decimalAlpha
 * @returns
 */
export function decimalAlphaToHex(decimalAlpha: number): string {
  // Ensure the input is within the valid range
  if (decimalAlpha < 0 || decimalAlpha > 1)
    throw new Error('Decimal alpha value must be between 0 and 1')

  // Convert decimal alpha to a hexadecimal value
  const alphaHex = Math.floor(decimalAlpha * 255)
    .toString(16)
    .toUpperCase()

  // Ensure the hexadecimal value is two digits long (e.g., 0A instead of A)
  if (alphaHex.length < 2) {
    return '0' + alphaHex
  } else {
    return alphaHex
  }
}

type GetTheme = <
  TDefaultValue =
    | Partial<
        ThemeConfig & {
          extend: Partial<ThemeConfig>
        }
      >
    | undefined,
>(
  path?: string | undefined,
  defaultValue?: TDefaultValue | undefined,
) => TDefaultValue

// * Plugins
import plugin from 'tailwindcss/plugin'
import headlessui from '@headlessui/tailwindcss'

// @ts-ignore
import { default as flattenColorPalette } from 'tailwindcss/lib/util/flattenColorPalette'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    textShadow: {
      sm: '0 0 0.125rem var(--tw-text-shadow, hsl(0 0% 0% / 0.25))',
      DEFAULT: '0 0 0.25rem var(--tw-text-shadow, hsl(0 0% 0% / 0.25))',
      md: '0 0 0.5rem var(--tw-text-shadow, hsl(0 0% 0% / 0.25))',
      lg: '0 0 0.75rem var(--tw-text-shadow, hsl(0 0% 0% / 0.25))',
      xl: '0 0 1rem var(--tw-text-shadow, hsl(0 0% 0% / 0.25))',
      '2xl': '0 0 2rem var(--tw-text-shadow, hsl(0 0% 0% / 0.25))',
      '3xl': '0 0 3rem var(--tw-text-shadow, hsl(0 0% 0% / 0.25))',
      none: 'none',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ matchUtilities, theme }) {
      const colors: { [key: string]: string } = {},
        opacities: { [key: string]: string } = flattenColorPalette(
          theme('opacity'),
        ),
        opacityEntries = Object.entries(opacities)

      Object.entries(flattenColorPalette(theme('colors'))).forEach((color) => {
        const [key, value] = color

        if (typeof key !== 'string' || typeof value !== 'string') return null

        colors[key] = value.replace(' / <alpha-value>', '')

        if (value.startsWith('#') && value.length === 7)
          opacityEntries.forEach(([opacityKey, opacityValue]) => {
            colors[`${key}/${opacityKey}`] = `${value}${decimalAlphaToHex(
              Number(opacityValue),
            )}`
          })

        if (value.startsWith('#') && value.length === 4)
          opacityEntries.forEach(([opacityKey, opacityValue]) => {
            colors[`${key}/${opacityKey}`] = `${value}${value.slice(
              1,
            )}${decimalAlphaToHex(Number(opacityValue))}`
          })

        if (value.startsWith('rgb') || value.startsWith('hsl'))
          opacityEntries.forEach(([opacityKey, opacityValue]) => {
            colors[`${key}/${opacityKey}`] = `${value.slice(
              0,
              -1,
            )} / ${opacityValue})`.replace(' / <alpha-value>', '')
          })
      })

      matchUtilities(
        {
          'text-shadow': (value) => {
            const cssProperties: CSSRuleObject = {}

            if (
              typeof value === 'string' &&
              (value.startsWith('#') ||
                value.startsWith('rgb') ||
                value.startsWith('hsl'))
            ) {
              cssProperties['--tw-text-shadow-color'] = value
            } else {
              cssProperties['text-shadow'] = value
            }

            return cssProperties
          },
        },
        { values: { ...theme('textShadow'), ...colors } },
      )
    }),
  ],
}

export default config
```

##### My Best Attempt

```
// utils/custom-tailwind-merge.ts

import { extendTailwindMerge } from 'tailwind-merge'
import colors from 'tailwindcss/colors'

const colorList: { [key: string]: string[] }[] = []
const excludedColors = [
  'black',
  'blueGray',
  'coolGray',
  'inherit',
  'transparent',
  'trueGray',
  'warmGray',
  'white',
]

Object.entries(colors).forEach(([colorName, valueList]) => {
  if (excludedColors.includes(colorName)) return

  colorList.push({ [colorName]: Object.keys(valueList) })
})

type AdditionalClassGroupIds = 'text-shadow'

export const twMerge = extendTailwindMerge<AdditionalClassGroupIds>({
  extend: {
    classGroups: {
      'text-shadow': [
        'sm',
        'DEFAULT',
        'md',
        'lg',
        'xl',
        '2xl',
        '3xl',
        'none',
        ...colorList,
        'transparent',
        'white',
        'black',
      ],
    },
  },
})
```

```
// components/link.tsx

import type { LinkProps } from '@/typings/components'
import { twMerge } from '@/utils/custom-tailwind-merge'

export default function Link({ children, className, href }: LinkProps) {
  const defaultClasses = 'text-blue-500'

  return (
    <a href={href} className={twMerge(defaultClasses, className)}>{children}</a>
  )
}
```

### Example

#### Input

```
import Link from '@/components/link'

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <Link href='https://andrilla.net' className='text-shadow-lg text-shadow-red-500'>Website</Link>
  )
}
```

#### Intended Output

`<a href='https://andrilla.net' class='text-blue-500 text-shadow-lg text-shadow-red-500'>Website</a>`

#### Actual Output

`<a href='https://andrilla.net' class='text-shadow-lg'>Website</a>`

Comment: It's not the best solution, but if anyone needs a quick fix, you can always apply `text-shadow` to a parent of the component that applies the color.